# How to split map with list as values into map with smaller list as values

Tags: java, java-8

I have an issue. I got a csv in enter, with values like :

```
99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000001
99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000002
99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000003
99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000004
99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000005
01,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000006
01,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000007
02,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000007
```

The name of the file is like : AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv

I succesfully read the file and put it in a list of Bar like :

```
[Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000001], 
Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000002], 
Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000003], 
Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000004], 
Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000005],
Bar[01,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000006], 
Bar[01,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000007],
Bar[02,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000007]]
```

and I need to put them into a map like :

```
baz = HashMap<Foo, List<Bar>>
```

Bar is the bean of a line in the csv and Foo is a bean created from some elements of Bar

For now, I successfully split the list to a map by the first column's values of the csv. Output of that :

```
Foo[99, TEST_ABDC, AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv, 0]=[Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000001], Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000002], Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000003], Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000004], Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000005]
Foo[01, TEST_ABDC, AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv, 0]=[Bar[01,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000006], Bar[01,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000007]]
Foo[02, TEST_ABDC, AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv, 0]=[Bar[02,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000007]
```

Here is how I do it :

```
baz = listBar.stream().distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b -> b.getFooFromBar(fileAbsolutePath)));
```

baz must be split by the first column of the csv and the iteration of the line per the first column value. Because it must not have more than N element in a list for a key. (in the example below : 2)

```
Foo[99, TEST_ABDC, AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv, 0]=[Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000001], Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000002]]
Foo[99, TEST_ABDC, AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv, 1]=[Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000003], Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000004]]
Foo[99, TEST_ABDC, AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv, 2]=[Bar[99,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000005]
Foo[01, TEST_ABDC, AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv, 0]=[Bar[01,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000006], Bar[01,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000007]]
Foo[02, TEST_ABDC, AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv, 0]=[Bar[02,TEST_ABDC,AB01,0000007]
```

I need to do it with java's streams.

I need to split the list in N element max per key. I have a huge amount of data (something like 10000 k+). It must be split in, for example, lists of 2k elements.

How can i do it, please?

Comment: This seems like a lot of information for the question. You have a Map<Foo, List<Bar>> and you want to use a stream to create a List<Map<Foo, List<Bar>> > where each List<Bar> has N max elements?

Comment: Hello @matt, no i want Map<Foo, List<Bar>> to a Map<Foo, List<Bar>> but, if the List<Bar> as more than n elements, i want to split it in (length(List<Bar>) % n) + 1 . for example, the list of my first key containts 5k element, and i want 2k element max per key, so after the split, there will be 3 keys: two with 2k elements and one with 1k elements. (Damn that worst. i'm so sorry for my bad english)

Comment: How do you want your keys to change? Eg if Foo a, maps to you 5k elements, what do you want the resulting 3 keys to be?

Comment: @matt Actually, either the map is created a first time with Foo class as key and in my Foo class there would be an attribute (like "number"). In the first load, number would be 0 and after split, each Foo would be incremented. Or during the first load, the attribute "number" would be set by an incremented value.

Comment: You can change your grouping by parameter. In the getFooFromBar return an appropriate Foo depending on how many elements have been added to a specific key. If you need help with that you should include that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to first chunk your lists into desierd length of sublists and get a `Map<Foo,List<List<Bar>>>`. To do so just add the following method to your main class:

```
static <T> List<List<T>>  chunk(List<T> list, int n){
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    return new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / n))
                                .values());
}
```

then add another constructor to your `Foo` class, which accepts a `Foo` and an `int` and to create a new `Foo` by copying the first three fields and apply the new param to the forth field

```
public Foo(final Foo foo, int field4) {
    this.field1 = foo.field1;
    this.field2 = foo.field2;
    this.field3 = foo.field3;
    this.field4 = field4;
}
```

Now you can use the above to stream over your `baz` map, chunk the values into sublist create new key-value pairs for each entry and flatmap and finally collect to map. Example:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<Foo,List<Bar>> baz =
            Map.of(new Foo("99", "TEST_ABDC", "AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv", 0),
                    List.of(new Bar("99","TEST_ABDC","AB01","0000001"),
                            new Bar("99","TEST_ABDC","AB01","0000002"),
                            new Bar("99","TEST_ABDC","AB01","0000003"),
                            new Bar("99","TEST_ABDC","AB01","0000004"),
                            new Bar("99","TEST_ABDC","AB01","0000005")),

                    new Foo("01", "TEST_ABDC", "AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv", 0),
                    List.of(new Bar("01","TEST_ABDC","AB01","0000006"),
                            new Bar("01","TEST_ABDC","AB01","0000007")),

                    new Foo("02", "TEST_ABDC", "AB01_TEST_ABDC_YYYYMMDD.csv", 0),
                    List.of(new Bar("02","TEST_ABDC","AB01","0000007")));


        Map<Foo,List<Bar>> result =
        baz.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> chunk(e.getValue(),2)))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(e -> IntStream.range(0, e.getValue().size())
                                       .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new Foo(e.getKey(),i),e.getValue().get(i))))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));

        result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    static <T> List<List<T>>  chunk(List<T> list, int n){
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        return new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / n))
                                    .values());
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    static class Foo{
        String field1;
        String field2;
        String field3;
        int    field4;

    public Foo(final Foo foo, int field4) {
        this.field1 = foo.field1;
        this.field2 = foo.field2;
        this.field3 = foo.field3;
        this.field4 = field4;
    }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo[" + field1 + ", " + field2 + ", " + field3 + ", " + field4 + ']';
        }
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    static class Bar{
        String field1;
        String field2;
        String field3;
        String field4;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bar[" + field1 + ", " + field2 + ", " + field3 + ", " + field4 + ']';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i like the idea. i'll try it later with more data. thank you